# SgnalR .NET server await value from client

Tags: c#, .net, signalr, async-await

im making a Server - Client application to make a server control in realtime SignalR technology.

I should want get list of object from client, with await to return values, look the example:

**Server:**

```
List<Site> Sites = (List<Site>)Clients.Caller.GetSiteList();
```

**Client:**

```
void GetSiteList()
{
      _triggerHubProxy.Invoke<int>("SetSiteList", new List<SIte>);
}
```

Like ajax request - Request -> Await return - Response.

How i can do it ?

Thanks for your attention! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method on the client should look like this:

```
async Task GetSiteList()
{
    await _triggerHubProxy.Invoke<int>("SetSiteList", new List<Site>());
}
```

and should be awaited by the method that invokes it. If you want to return the value you need to change the method to the following:

```
async Task<int> GetSiteList()
{
    return await _triggerHubProxy.Invoke<int>("SetSiteList", new List<Site>());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client

```
    var stocks = await stockTickerHub.Invoke<IEnumerable<Stock>>("AddStock", new Stock() { Symbol = "MSFT" });
    foreach (Stock stock in stocks)
    {
        textBox.Text += string.Format("Symbol: {0} price: {1}\n", stock.Symbol, stock.Price);
    }
```

> The Invoke method executes asynchronously and returns a Task object.
>   If you don't specify await or .Wait(), the next line of code will
>   execute before the method that you invoke has finished executing.

this should work :P

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible using SignalR to get a return value on the server from a client method. Instead you should pass the site list from the client to the server as an argument. So this:

```
public void MyServerHubMethod()
{
    // The following line will throw an InvalidCastException since
    // Client methods cannot return values to the server.
    List<Site> sites = (List<Site>)Clients.Caller.GetSiteList();
    DoSomethingWithSites(sites);
}
```

Becomes this:

```
public void MyServerHubMethod(List<Site> sites)
{
    DoSomethingWithSites(sites);
}
```

Which can be called like this:

```
List<Site> sites = GetSites();
await _triggerHubProxy.Invoke("MyServerHubMethod", sites);
```